# Seek to Beginning of Kafka Topic Using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using a Kafka Stream in PySpark, is it possible to seek to the beginning of a Kafka topic without creating a new consumer group?

For example, I have the following code snippet:

```
...
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 pyspark-shell'
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

sc = SparkContext('local[2]', appName="MyStreamingApp_01")
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
ssc.StreamingContext(sc, 30)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper_ip, 'group-id', {'messages': 1})

counted = kafkaStream.count()
...
```

My goal is to do something along the lines of

```
kafkaStream.seekToBeginningOfTopic()
```

Currently, I'm creating a new consumer group to re-read from the beginning of the topic, e.g.:

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper, 'group-id-2', {'messages': 1}, {"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})
```

Is this the proper way to consume a topic from the beginning using PySpark?

Comment: You can commit offset 0 for all subscribed partitions.